# How to use an execute command to test for an item/s in a chest?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to detect if a player is standing on a chest using an execute command then if so detect what is in that chest and give an output. E.G Player is standing on a chest there is 64 stone in the chest if so give a redstone or score board output?

I have tried

```
execute @p ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~-2 ~ command_block 0 replace {command:"testforblock ~ ~1 ~ chest -1 {Items:[{id:minecraft:stone,Slot:0b,Count:64b}]}"
```

and

```
execute @p ~ ~ ~ testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ chest -1 {Items:[{id:minecraft:stone,Slot:0b,Count:64b}]}
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm actually not sure how you would attack this. `/execute` will fire a successful output if it's able to successfully execute iirc, so I'm not sure how you would be able to do this. There might be shenannegians you could do with `/execute detect`, but I don't know if that sort of command can be that sophisticated or not.

Answer (score 2):

In order to target that player afterwards, you must use CommandStats to track the success of a command.

## Prerequisites:

Objective to hold the return value.

```
/scoreboard objectives add AboveChest dummy
```

Applying the "AffectedBlocks" trigger to all players, who will then set their own "AboveChest" score depending on the success of block-related commands. This may need to run on a clock if new players can join at any time.

```
/stats entity @a set AffectedBlocks @a[c=1] AboveChest
```

In order for CommandStats to modify a target's score, that target must be tracked prior. This may also need to run on a clock.

```
/scoreboard players add @a AboveChest 0
```

## Clock commands:

The following must be run on a clock in numerical order.

1. Cause players to run a `/testforblock` to find the chest. If the command is successful, that player will have their "AboveChest" score set to 1. If unsuccessful, that player will have their score set to 0.

   ```
   /execute @a ~ ~ ~ testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:chest -1 {Items:[{id:"minecraft:stone",Count:64b,Slot:0b}]}
   ```
2. Target players based on their "AboveChest" score.

   ```
   /say @a[score_AboveChest_min=1] is above a chest containing a stack of 64 stone.
   ```

Comment: Still just outputs                                                                                                 failed to execute testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:chest -1 {Items:[{id:"minecraft:stone",Count:64b,Slot:0b}]}

Comment: @Fluffkin1 That would be because you don't have a chest with the first slot containing 64 stone blocks 1 block below the player. You have to ensure the chest exists first.

Comment: "@Fluffkin1 That would be because you don't have a chest with the first slot containing 64 stone blocks 1 block below the player. You have to ensure the chest exists first" it does exist

Comment: Chests are not a full block's height. When a player stands on top of a chest, their feet are in the same block as the chest. Therefore, do not lower the Y by 1, this will target the block below the chest. Use the same block coordinates of the player.

Answer (score 0):

## 1.13+ Update to [Skylinerw's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/260502/250180)

1.13 has completely changed commands. Are you playing 1.13 and have the same question? This is the answer for you.

### Prerequisites

1. Objective:

   ```
   /scoreboard objectives add AboveChest dummy
   ```
2. Set the player's initial score.

   ```
   /scoreboard players set @a AboveChest 0
   ```

`/stats` is deprecated, use `/execute store` instead.

### Clock commands

1. Find chest and store success/failure in scoreboard variable.

   ```
   /execute as @a at @s if block ~ ~ ~ chest{Items:[{id:"minecraft:stone",Count:64b,Slot:0b}]}
   ```
2. Target players who have a score of 1. Use whatever command you want and this target selector to get them

   ```
   @e[scores={AboveChest=1}]
   ```